# Tail.select Datatables

Tags: datatables, tail.select

I am trying to use tail.select from https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select.
On the first page load its running well like what I want.

[image]

but when I call the row.add method from datatables, each dropdown not working anymore.
[image]

Hope somebody can help me to solve this issue.

Best Regards

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

In the question's code, I assume that `$('#master-row').html()` is returning a fragment of HTML - possibly the contents of a `<td>`.

However, the DataTable `row.add()` function expects a JavaScript data structure - a JS array or object.

You can provide a variable containing "master row" data using something like this:

```js
var masterRow = [
  "",
  "<select class=\"select2\"><option>first</option><option>second</option><option>third</option></select>",
  "<textarea rows=\"3\" cols=\"20\"></textarea>"
];
```

It doesn't have to be hard-coded JS like this. It could also be sourced from an ajax call.  But for this demo, I will use the above approach.

You can now use this "master row", containing three column values, as follows:

Here is the full HTML page for the demo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
  
  <!-- tail.select -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tail.select@latest/css/tail.select-default.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tail.select@latest/js/tail.select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <button type="button" class="btn-add">New Row!</button> 

    <br><br>
    
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var masterRow = [
  "",
  "<select class=\"select2\"><option>first</option><option>second</option><option>third</option></select>",
  "<textarea rows=\"3\" cols=\"20\"></textarea>"
];

var dataSet = [];
dataSet.push(masterRow);

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
      paging: false,
      searching: false,
      ordering: false,
      columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 0,
        title:  "Num",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          console.log(data);
          return meta.row + 1;
        }
      },
      {
        targets: 1,
        title: "Select Column"
      },
      {
        targets: 2,
        title: "Textarea Column"
      }
      ]
    }).on('draw', function() {
          tail.select(".select2", {
            search: true
          });
    });

    table.draw();
    
    $('.btn-add').click(function() {
      table.row.add(masterRow).draw();
    });
    
  } );
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Notes**:

The `dataSet` variable takes the master row array and adds it into another outer array. This is needed so that we have a full 2-dimensional data structure for DataTables to use when it first loads the table. It is a 2D structure, but with only one (initial) row of data:

[image]

When we click on the "new row" button, it uses the `masterRow` variable as its source for the contents of the new row, resulting in this:

[image]

As you can see, the table has a new row, and the drop-downs are working as expected.

You can see the official documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) for more details about the `row.add()` API call.